# Inaccurate output in C recursive program

Tags: c, arrays, function, recursion

**C Recursive function error**

I am studying "Practical C Programming, 3rd Edition"
by Steve Oualline and it contains this assignment to make a program which has the following requirements.

> Exercise 9-3: Write a function `count(number, array, length)` that counts the
>   number of times `number` appears in `array`. The array has `length` elements. The
>   function should be recursive. Write a test program to go with the function.

I coded the program in like 15 minutes but my output is not exactly what I want. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int length;
int count(int num2count, int array[length], int size);

int main(void)
{
  char check;
  int i = 0;
  long int num_to_be_counted;
  int ans;
  printf("Please enter the length of array:");
  scanf("%d",&length);
  long int numbers[length];

  for(int i = 0; i != length; ++i) {
    numbers[i] = 0;
  }

  printf("Enter the array:");

  while( check != '\n') {
    scanf("%li",&numbers[i]);
    ++i;
    check = getchar();
  }

  printf("Enter the number to be counted in the array:");

  scanf("%d",&num_to_be_counted);

  for(int i = 0; i != length; ++i) {
    numbers[i] = 0;
  }

  ans = count(num_to_be_counted,numbers,length);

  printf("The number appears %d times in the array.",ans);

  return 0;
}


int count(int num2count, int array[length], int size)
{
  static int times = 0;
  static int i = 0;

  if ( array[i] == num2count) {
    ++times;
  }

  if(i == size) {
    return times;
  }

  while( i != length ) {
    ++i;
    count(num2count,array,length);
  }
}
```

The program is ok with no errors (except logical ones), Here's the sample input and output

```
length = 4
numbers = 1 2 2 4
number_to_count = 2
Output: 4
```

The function doesn't even count the number to be counted; it just returns the size of array e.g in this case 4.

Any sort of help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Don't use global or `static` variables.

Comment: @melpomene Elaboration please?

Comment: Why are you reassigning all the values in the array to `0` after you accept them from the user?

Comment: @GoodDeeds Oh, that's an old nasty habit.

Comment: So you wrote the code in 15 minutes and did not take a minute to debug. me to learn debugging/testing takes much longer that writing the code.

Comment: @Muneeb What's unclear?

Comment: I tried running your code and got a segmentation fault. You might want to check your recursive function and put the loop where you check `if(i == size)` at the start of the function

Comment: @melpomene Why not use static there, How will the variables hold their values in next recursive function call if i do not use static?

Comment: @melpomene And also i don't see any problem with using global in my code?

Comment: @Muneeb Global variables are bad by default. You should have a good reason to create a global variable. This program doesn't need globals.

Comment: @Muneeb Your local variables aren't supposed to "hold their values" between calls. E.g. you should be able to call `count` more than once in the same program and get correct results.

Comment: @Olaf That's the bitter truth about programming :p

Comment: When you ask for help, remove redundant ( system("cls"); ) code and fix indentation and overall formatting before posting. I fixed it for you now.

Answer (score 2):

Problems in your code:

- Your code resets the input array to `0` before doing anything with it.
- `count` accesses `array[i]` before checking `if(i == size)`, i.e. you have an out-of-bounds access.
- Your recursive call to `count` is wrapped in a loop. This makes no sense because the nested `count` invocation will loop itself (and in each iteration call `count` again, which will loop itself, ...).
- All local variables in `count` are `static`, which means the function is useless: You can't call it more than once in any program. A better test program to demonstrate this would be something like:

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      printf("%d appears %d times in the array\n", numbers[i], count(numbers[i], numbers, length));
  }
  ```

Other problems:

- `int i;` is unused in your `main()` function.
- `check` is uninitialized the first time you check it.
- Assigning the result of `getchar()` to a `char` is a bad idea in general; `getchar()` returns `int` for a reason.
- There's a type error in your program: `numbers` is declared as an array of `long int`, but you're passing it to a function taking an array of `int`.
- You're missing `#include <stdlib.h>` for `system()`.

Comment: Why do i need to include stdlib when i can access the system() without it?

Comment: @Muneeb Including `<stdlib.h>` will provide a declaration for `system`, which allows the compiler to warn you if you call it with incorrect arguments. Without a declaration in scope, `system("...")` will work (because `system` happens to return `int`), but the compiler would also have accepted `system(1, 2, 3)` (wrong number of arguments, wrong types). That kind of thing usually leads to a crash at runtime (or garbage results).

Comment: How long have you been coding and did you also get errors in literally every program you coded when you were new to programming. I actually started coding 6 months ago and wanted to know about how well i am going through learning coding. Also if you could provide me with a few tips to write better and less error-prone code?

Comment: @Muneeb: I can't answer for Melpomene, but for me, it's over 30 years, and yes, for a few weeks, I got errors all the time.  Sometimes I now get a significant chunk of code to compile on the first time, but not as often as I'd like.  And sometimes it works correctly first time it is run — that happens more often.  As to tips: pay heed to every warning your compiler gives you, and fix it before running the program. The compiler knows more about C than you do; if it deigns to warn you, it's because it is pretty damn sure you've made a mistake. Assume it is correct. (Compiler bugs are very rare!)

Comment: You seem to have missed '`count()` does not always return a value, and the (non-)returned value from the recursive call is ignored'.

Answer (score 0):

Here there are many problems.

First of all this is much more complicated than it should be. You used `static` which is not at all needed.

The answer is wrong because you have calculated multiple times.

This is how it should be. You can try to understand this code.

```
int count(int num2count, int array[], int size)
{
    if( size<= 0) return 0;
    return (array[size-1]==num2count)+count(num2count,array,size-1);
}
```

or

```
int count(int num2count, int array[], int size)
{
    if( size<= 0) return 0;
    return (array[0]==num2count)+count(num2count,array+1,size-1);
}
```

Why should I not use `static` in recursion? It is nothing wrong but it's a bad design because it is a problem when you have thousands of lines of code and lots of functions. Then to track which variable caused any problem or to debug it would be really tedious. <sup>1</sup>

#### Your problem

```
int count(int num2count, int array[length], int size)
{
    static int times = 0;  // bad design and unnecessary.
    static int i = 0;

   if ( array[i] == num2count)
   {
    ++times;
   }



   if(i == size)
   {
    return times;
   }
   while( i < length ) <----check
   {
     ++i;
     count(num2count,array,length);
   }

}
```

### Also `count()` doesn't return any value so no use  storing it in a variable .

<sup>1</sup><sub>I have just mentioned few problems and the clean solution to the problem. For a detail description refer to  **melpomene**'s answer.</sub>

Comment: @coderredoc Why is using static wrong here, How will the variables hold their values in the next phase when the function is called recursively if static is not used?

Comment: @melpomene.: check please sir.

Comment: The `[length]` part is pointless. You could just declare the parameter as `int array[]` or `int *array`. (The rest looks good. As an additional exercise, make it count from left to right. :-)

Comment: I am getting really confused here people, Would someone please tell me the main problem in my code (just the problem, not the solution. I enjoy solving problems myself).

Comment: @melpomene.: Hey..to count from left to right..I have to change the `int*` itself? Going right?

Comment: @coderredoc Depends on what you mean by "change". You have to pass different arguments to the recursive call. You don't have to change the function declaration.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't reset the array values before passing them to your function.
2. The while loop in count makes no sense, rethink the way it works, maybe print out the recursive calls. Also count may not return anything, fix it.
3. As already mentioned in the comments, check for being out of bounds before accessing array elements.